# Workarounds for overflow-y:hidden in non supported browsers

Tags: css, overflow

I am using `overflow-y:hidden` to create a slideshow that fits the viewport without any overflow. This works perfectly in `chrome (version 54)`, but doesn't work in `Microsoft edge (version 25)` or `Firefox (version 31)`, where the content is overflowing.

I found out from the MDN documentation that this property is an experimental one and not widely supported.I tried adding vendor prefixes also, but it doesn't work.

Are there any workarounds to this?

Comment: I don't see how `overflow-y` could be an experimental technology... it's supported since IE5 unless I'm missing something obvious. Can you share some code? So **please create a [mcve]**

Comment: As suggested, you need to post a code snippet that reproduce the issue, as this is most likely something else that cause a scroll, elsewhere.